# Are there some potential problems when invoking the STL containers with the allocator without construct() and destroy() functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, ros, allocation

Should these member functions (i.e: `max_size()`, `construct()` and `destroy()`) be implemented when defining an allocator by myself with **std=c++11** option?

Are there some **potential problems** that I should be aware of when invoking the  STL containers with the allocator without these aforementioned member functions?

As per https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator, these member functions are **deprecated in C++17** and **removed in C++20**.

As per the implementation of ROS2(https://github.com/ros2/realtime_support/tree/master/tlsf_cpp) which is commonly used in robot control, there are no such member functions indeed. It's important to emphasize that this implementation is targeted for `C++14`.

**ADDED**:

As per the article(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/allocators?view=msvc-160), which says that[emphasise mine]:

A minimal allocator requires much less boilerplate and enable you to focus on the allocate and deallocate member functions which do all of the work. When creating a minimal allocator, **do not implement any members** except the ones shown in the example below:
a converting copy constructor (see example)
operator==
operator!=
allocate
deallocate

But if I really remove the implenmentation of `construct()` and `destory()`, the compilers(gcc5.4, clang-6.0 and clang-8.0) complain that it could not found such implenmentation when std::list uses self-defined allocator.

Comment: If building for C++11, you need to provide what C++11 requires.    Deprecation in C++17 and removal in C++20 are not retrospective - the requirement still exists for C++11.   You might get lucky and find that some (possibly even all) standard containers don't use those member functions of the allocator - for a particular C++11 implementation.    But that doesn't mean every implementation compliant with C++11 will do the same - and your code is not guaranteed to build or function correctly with *other* C++11 implementations, unless your allocator provides the required member functions.

Comment: @Peter Thank you for your clarification. But the aforementioned git is targeted for **`C++14`** indeed, and these member functions are not provided indeed. And ROS2 is a **mature** project.

Comment: However, mature ROS2 may be, it is still incorrect if you are building for C++11.    The C++ standard you are building for is the yardstick for assessing correctness of code (or implementations).    Code like that used in ROS2 is not a yardstick for assessing correctness against the standard.     Presumably, ROS2 is targeting particular implementations for which it happens to work.   That doesn't mean it is guaranteed to work with every C++11 (or C++14) implementation.   Because it does not comply with requirements of C++11 or C++14 standards.

Comment: @Peter I see. There is a commonly seen phenomenon that `C++14` is rarely mentioned on https://en.cppreference.com/ comparing to `C++11`,`C++17` and `C++20`. I am really interested in the reasons.

Comment: There aren't many differences between C++11 and C++14.

Comment: @Peter Here is some description quoted from MSDN. It's very long, I added it to the original post.In short words, it does not suggest to implement `construct()` and `destory()` in C++11.